# Почему пишет что TypeError: 'str' object is not callable не могу понять

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, строки

```
class Wizard:
    def __init__(self, name, rating, age):
        self.name = name
        self.rating = rating
        self.age = age

    def change_rating(self, value):
        if self.rating + value > self.rating:
            self.rating += value
            self.age -= abs(value) // 10
            if self.rating < 1:
                self.rating = 1
            if self.rating > 100:
                self.rating = 100
        else:
            self.rating += value
            self.age += abs(value) // 10
            if self.rating < 1:
                self.rating = 1
            if self.rating > 100:
                self.rating = 100

    def __call__(self, value):
        return (int(value) - self.age) * self.rating

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Wizard {self.name} with {self.rating} rating looks {self.age} years old'

    def __iadd__(self, string):
        value = len(string)
        if self.rating + value > self.rating:
            self.rating += value
            self.age -= abs(value) // 10
            if self.rating < 1:
                self.rating = 1
            if self.rating > 100:
                self.rating = 100
        else:
            self.rating -= value
            self.age += abs(value) // 10
            if self.rating < 1:
                self.rating = 1
            if self.rating > 100:
                self.rating = 100
        return self.__str__()

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if self.rating == other.rating:
            if self.age == other.age:
                return self.name > other.name
            else:
                return self.age > other.age
        else:
            return self.rating > other.rating

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.rating == other.rating:
            if self.age == other.age:
                return self.name < other.name
            else:
                return self.age < other.age
        else:
            return self.rating < other.rating

    def __ge__(self, other):
        if self.rating == other.rating:
            if self.age == other.agr:
                return self.name >= other.name
            else:
                return self.age >= other.age
        else:
            return self.rating >= other.rating

    def __le__(self, other):
        if self.rating == other.rating:
            if self.age == other.age:
                return self.name <= other.name
            else:
                return self.age <= other.age
        else:
            return self.rating <= other.rating

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.rating == other.rating:
            if self.age == other.age:
                return self.name == other.name
            else:
                return self.age == other.age
        else:
            return self.rating == other.rating

    def __ne__(self, other):
        if self.rating == other.rating:
            if self.age == other.age:
                return self.name != other.name
            else:
                return self.age != other.age
        else:
            return self.rating != other.rating


wd = Wizard("Hawl", 75, 27)
print(wd)
wd.change_rating(23)
wd += "great magician"
print(wd)
print(wd(42))
```

Comment: справа я вижу шесть вопросов по такой ошибке. Ты их уже изучил?

Comment: так помощь нужна?

Answer (score 1):

Метод `def __iadd__(self, string)` в текущей реализации возвращает строку

```
return self.__str__()
```

Поэтому после выполнения `wd += "great magician"` в переменной `wd` будет храниться строка, а строку нельзя вызвать как функцию, поэтому код `print(wd(42))` и вызывает ошибку.

Для исправления, достаточно вместо строки вернуть `self`